# What is the equivalent of dmesg on WinXP and later?

Tags: windows, hardware-failure, logging

The output from dmesg is often useful for determining which hardware is detected on a given system but it is also very useful for looking at hardware errors such as when wifi interface won't work or when a a hard drive is about to die.

I would very much like to learn about a Windows alternative to read kernel messages of that sort. I imagine It could be useful in determining the cause of the bsod in some cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the system error log ("eventvwr.msc"), but it's not as descriptive as dmesg. There's also C:\BOOT.LOG, where available.

Comment: I will have to look closer at that viewer thing. Doesn't look very useful right-off.

Comment: Linux generally has better messages than windows because there is the possibility of the user hacking the source and fixing it. A lot of Windows stuff fails silently or opaquely. Having said that, eventvwr offers a link to the Knowledgebase for an error message which is often quite good.

Answer (score 4):

see [wevtutil](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732848.aspx) and [Sysinternals' psloglist](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897544.aspx)

Comment: Specifically `wevutil qe system /f:Text /rd | more` is probably the closest command-line equivalent for the Windows System log.  But the messages are not as informative.